# Issue with exim4u

Tags: email, debian, exim

I am using exim4u for a mail server on debian.  Everything has been working fine until recently.  I have not done anything to the server from the time it was working until now.  I have a domain set up and is receiving and sending mail correctly.  When i put a forwarding address in to a gmail address, I can still receive and send email from my webmail client but it never makes it to gmail.  I have check logs and this is what I have found

```
2012-04-01 18:47:04 1SEPns-0000aN-Br DKIM: d=gmail.com s=20120113 c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2012-04-01 18:47:10 1SEPns-0000aN-Br H=mail-bk0-f43.google.com [209.85.214.43] Warning: X-Spam_score: -0.3
2012-04-01 18:47:10 1SEPns-0000aN-Br <= xxx@gmail.com H=mail-bk0-f43.google.com [209.85.214.43] P=esmtps X=TLS1.0:RSA_ARCFOUR_MD5:16 S=3424 id=CAGZkSKbYc7SJR+yXTgG8ubQvx4PNb0CwHG1DDKGeZ-qFiA$
2012-04-01 18:47:11 1SEPns-0000aN-Br => /home/mail/mydomain.com/support/Maildir (xxx@mydomain.com) <xxx@mydomain.com> R=virtual_domains T=virtual_delivery
2012-04-01 18:47:12 1SEPns-0000aN-Br => xxx@gmail.com <xxx@mydomain.com> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.225.27] X=TLS1.0:RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1:16
2012-04-01 18:47:12 1SEPns-0000aN-Br Completed
```

I am not a mail server person so im not sure what everything here is saying.  It appears to me that it is successfully sending mail to gmail though.  I have checked my spam folder as well and nothing there either.

If it would help to have some more information from my server, let me know because Im not sure what would be of help here.

Comment: Can you explain this better: When i put a forwarding address in to a gmail address ?

Comment: Sorry... exim4u allows you to forward email to a different address.   I am forwarding email sent to xxx@mydomain.com to xxx@gmail.com.  This is done via a setting in the web gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is having this issue.  try sending a message to your exim mail account from a different email account that is not being forwarded, for example... If you have

> abc@gmail.example.com
>
> def@eximserver.example.org

you are wanting to forward anything sent to def@eximserver.example.org to abc@gmail.example.com,  Do not send a test message from abc@gmail.example.com as this will just cause the message to vanish when it is forwarded to you.  With regards to gmail addresses I feel like this is a flaw in gmail's servers.

Answer (score 1):

One of the "problems" with gmail is that it tends to drop email that comes from an IP address without reverse DNS. So check if you have it enabled.